# update spinner in a recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner

In a recylerview containing spinner, how to add more items dynamically in the spinner(AT THAT PARTICULAR POSITION ONLY)... Right now when i am updating the child spinner, all the spinners of the recylerview are getting updated. Please help me to update only the spinner at that particular position(of recylerview).

Following is my Adapter(which is inflating these spinners in a recylerview):

```
public class OfferRideRegularListViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<OfferRideRegularListViewAdapter.MyViewHolder> implements SelectTimeFragment.SelectedTimeListener
{
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    CustomSpinnerAdapter leavingTimeAdpater,returningTimneAdpater;
    ArrayList<CommonListViewItems> leavingTimeItemsList,returningTimeItemsList;
    List<String> checkedItemsList;
    Context context;
    View convertView;
    private static final int LEAVING_TIMEPICKER_FRAGMENT = 2;
    private static final int RETURNING_TIMEPICKER_FRAGMENT = 3;
    private Fragment fragment;
    private int selectedDayPosition;
    private ArrayList<CommonListViewItems> leavingTimeOfDayList,returningTimeOfDayList;
    private ViewGroup viewGroup;
    private int TIMEPICKER_FRAGMENT=0;
    private CommonListViewItems items;
    RecylerView recyclerView;

    public OfferRideRegularListViewAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<CommonListViewItems> leavingTimeItemsList,ArrayList<CommonListViewItems> returningTimeItemsList,RecylerView recyclerView) {
        this.context=context;
        this.recyclerView = recyclerView;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.leavingTimeItemsList = leavingTimeItemsList;
        this.returningTimeItemsList = returningTimeItemsList;
        checkedItemsList = Arrays.asList(context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.week_days));
        leavingTimeAdpater=new CustomSpinnerAdapter(context,R.layout.common_listview_item,this.leavingTimeItemsList);
        returningTimneAdpater = new CustomSpinnerAdapter(context,R.layout.common_listview_item,this.returningTimeItemsList);
        leavingTimeOfDayList = new ArrayList<CommonListViewItems>();
        for (int i=0;i<checkedItemsList.size();i++)
        {
            items = new CommonListViewItems();
            items.setlistItem(leavingTimeItemsList.get(0).getlistItem());
            leavingTimeOfDayList.add(items);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.layout_offer_ride_regular_list_items, parent, false);

        convertView = itemView;
        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.checkDay.setText(checkedItemsList.get(position));
        holder.spinnerLeavingTime.setAdapter(leavingTimeAdpater);
        holder.spinnerReturningTime.setAdapter(returningTimneAdpater);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return checkedItemsList.size();
    }


    public int getCount() {
        return checkedItemsList.size();
    }

    public void showSelectTimeDialog(int TIMEPICKER_FRAGMENT)
    {
        this.TIMEPICKER_FRAGMENT = TIMEPICKER_FRAGMENT;
        FragmentManager fm = ((MainActivity)context).getFragmentManager();
        SelectTimeFragment selectTimeFragment = new SelectTimeFragment();
        selectTimeFragment.setSelectedTimeListener(this);
        selectTimeFragment.show(fm,"TimePicker");
    }


    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        public CheckBox checkDay;
        public Spinner spinnerLeavingTime;
        public Spinner spinnerReturningTime;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            checkDay=(CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.checkedDay);
            spinnerLeavingTime=(Spinner)view.findViewById(R.id.spinner_leavingTime);
            spinnerReturningTime=(Spinner)view.findViewById(R.id.spinner_returningTime);

            spinnerLeavingTime.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    if (position == (leavingTimeAdpater.getCount() - 1)) {
                        hideKeyboard(view);
                        selectedDayPosition = getAdapterPosition();
                        showSelectTimeDialog(LEAVING_TIMEPICKER_FRAGMENT);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String onTimeSelected(String selectedTime) {
        updateChildSpinnerList(selectedTime);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTimeNotSelected(boolean noTimeSelected) {

    }

    private void updateChildSpinnerList(String selectedTime)
    {

        if (selectedTime!=null)
        {
            CommonListViewItems items;
            switch (TIMEPICKER_FRAGMENT)
            {
                case LEAVING_TIMEPICKER_FRAGMENT:
                {
                    items = new CommonListViewItems();
                    items.setlistItem(selectedTime);
                    items = new CommonListViewItems();
                    items.setlistItem("Change...");
                    leavingTimeOfDayList.remove(selectedDayPosition);
                    leavingTimeOfDayList.add(selectedDayPosition, items);
                    Spinner spinner= (Spinner) recyclerView.getChildAt(selectedDayPosition).findViewById(R.id.spinner_leavingTime);
                    notifyItemChanged(selectedDayPosition);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {

        }



    }
}
```

Fragment from where I am calling this adapter:

```
offerRideRegularListViewAdapter = new OfferRideRegularListViewAdapter(getActivity(),getLeavingTimeList(),getReturningTimeList(),listEachDay);

        listEachDay.setAdapter(offerRideRegularListViewAdapter);
```

Following is the CustomSpinnerAdpater:

```
public class CustomSpinnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CommonListViewItems> {
    CommonListViewItems servicesItem;
    Context context;
    int layoutId;
    private ArrayList<CommonListViewItems> itemsArrayList;

    public CustomSpinnerAdapter(Context context, int layoutId, ArrayList<CommonListViewItems> itemsArrayList)
    {
        super(context,layoutId,itemsArrayList);
        this.context = context;
        this.layoutId=layoutId;
        this.itemsArrayList=itemsArrayList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return itemsArrayList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CommonListViewItems getItem(int position) {
        return itemsArrayList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return getCustomView(position,convertView,parent);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return getCustomView(position,convertView,parent);
    }

    private View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        final ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView==null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView=inflater.inflate(layoutId,parent,false);
            holder=new ViewHolder();
            servicesItem = new CommonListViewItems();
            holder.textView=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_listItems);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }
        final CommonListViewItems servicesItem =(CommonListViewItems)itemsArrayList.get(position);
        holder.textView.setText(servicesItem.getlistItem());
        return convertView;
    }

    private class ViewHolder
    {
        public TextView textView;
    }

}
```

And the CommonListViewItems class:

```
public class CommonListViewItems {

    String listItem;

    public String getlistItem() {
        return listItem;
    }

    public void setlistItem(String listItem) {
        this.listItem = listItem;
    }
}
```

The recyclerview looks like this:

[image]

and on clicking the spinner i want to add more items(Time) from TimePickerDialog, but the added item is getting added to each spinner, I want to add only to that particular spinner which is touched:

Thanks in advance...

Comment: I tried, i really tried. But your code is so hard to follow, no wonder you cannot find the error. However I believe this is because all your views share the same spinner adapter and hence the same data.

Comment: please try now, i have removed the uneccessary code. Please try now... I really need it..

Comment: Have one spinner adapter instance and one spinner data per you ViewHolder. this way they are independent of each other

Comment: No i'm not going to re-write your application for you. I'm trying to help by pointing you in the right direction. As far as i'm concerned, just like the cliche saying in school, you gotta try it yourself. People here will help you, not do you job for you.
https://www.raywenderlich.com/126528/android-recyclerview-tutorial. Here is a tutorial that describes the holder logic in detail. And as I said before, if all your holders look at the same data for their spinners, when you change data for one, all will be affected. Hence, as a basic approach they all must share a different copy of the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, a different instance for each Adapter with a different dataset can update the specific spinner adapter at the selected position in the recyclerview.

I solved my problem like this:

1. Create an ArrayList of ArrayLists like:

   ```
   ArrayList<String> [] list = new ArrayList[predefined_size];
   for (int i=0;i<7;i++)
   {
       list[i]=new ArrayList<String>();
       list[i].addAll(parentList); //parentList is an ArrayList of custom items;
   }
   ```
2. Now in `onBindViewHolder` of `recyclerview`, `setAdapter` for `Spinner` with a different instance of `SpinnerAdpater` with a separate dataset(list or arraylist etc.), like this:

   ```
   public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
   holder.spinner.setAdapter(new CustomSpinnerAdapter(context,R.layout.common_listview_item,list[position]));
   ```
3. And then we can add items to the list or adapter of specific spinner, like this:

   ```
   list[position].add(item);
   ```

And in this way, only that `spinner` will be updated which we want to update // ie the spinner at the given postion.

***Hence, updating the spinner at the given position in a RecyclerView is achieved.***

Answer (score 1):

You need multiple instances of the same spinnerAdapter with different datasets.

You have done the same for the checkday textview by using the arraylist. In that case, in the onBindViewHolder the value of the day depends on the position in the list. Try to do the same.

Comment: How to link the same spinner with different instances of the adapter ? How to setadapter in spinner to different instances of the adapter ? Please tell..

Comment: in onbinderview()  put this holder.spinnerLeavingTime.setAdapter(new CustomSpinnerAdapter(dataset.get(position)); where dataset is an arraylist or map for each day of the week

Comment: Why do we need to pass dataset.get(position) instead of dataset ?

Comment: You want for each listview item an array of times right? Each spinner will have several values of times which might be different for each row in the list. So you need an arraylist or array for each row. And you need to keep all that in a new array or arralylist which i named dataset.

Comment: Thanks a lot masp, u saved me. It worked like a charm, sorry for replying so late, actually i tried it just now..

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear from the code you posted, what each of the rowItems are, so I'll layout how I might approach this:

1) Make an individual layout for an arbitrary row item, this should contain the CheckBox, the TextView to hold the day, and the Spinner that you want to fill with times.

2) Create an Object that represents all of these together, like 'DayAndTimeSelection' or similar.  Each of these objects will have their own Spinner instance and their own SpinnerAdapter instance, because you need to make the association between that row's Spinner and the set of possible times that are in that spinner.

VERIFY THAT THIS WORKS AS EXPECTED FOR ONE ROW ITEM BEFORE PROCEEDING....

3) Make an outer 'DayAndTimeItemListAdapter' that handles the entire collection of individual rows. In your example, there will only be 7 items in this list, but if you change to a monthly view, you might get 30.  If you do your abstraction correctly for each of the rows, changing values within each of the row items, adding times to the spinner and getting/setting checkboxes will be clear. The outer Adapter is the one where you'll be recycling the views, so make sure that the getView() and getItem() for your list work as expected, and that each row has a separate and unique Spinner and SpinnerAdapter instance (look at the id after the '@' symbol in that row's Spinner & SpinnerAdapter...like: 'SpinnerAdapter@1234')

4) Profit...

Comment: You mean to say differenet layout for different row ? Not inflating the same layout, but linking different layouts ?